# Disable Android Switch's default action on click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, switch-statement

### What I'm trying to do

I am trying to use Android's Switch element to login or logout users from Facebook and LinkedIn's APIs, as shown in the image.

[image]

### My issue

Currently the toggles trigger automtically on user click. I'd liek them to only move on command when I the API has confirmed that the user's login state has successfully changed.

### My attempt

I have tried to use `myLoginSwitch.setClickable(false);` however this doesn't seem to have any affect.

### What I'm trying to avoid

I imagine this could be done with a custom made switch element, however for obvious reasons I am trying to avoid that solution!

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried just disabling it with setEnabled(false)?

Comment: Set a onclick listener on switch . And validate inside it weather to toggle switch or not . Although I think this is not a good design approach for account handling . You can come up with a better design except switch .

Comment: @hardanger please see my answer. Just updated.

Comment: You need to set an on click listener like I demonstrated in my answer. setClickable just makes it so you can or can't click the Switch, as opposed to coding what should happen after clicking it. How does Android know what to do after only setting setClickable to true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all the thoughts & answers!

Disabling the button wasn't something I was keen on and sadly using `onClick()` isn't enough to overwrite the default action.

However onTouch did the trick perfectly! If anyone is doing something similar, this is the function:

```
myLoginSwitch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        myLoginSwitch.setClickable(false);
        myLoginLogoutFunc();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Notice I used pseudocode to handle the facebook login. But Facebook or any other organization is going to provide methods for you to deal with login success/failure in their API. Use the method to set the Switch to "checked" if logged in successfully or set checked to false otherwise:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final android.widget.Switch facebookSwitch = (android.widget.Switch)findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

        //This pseudocode programs what to do after a login attempt.
        //Real API's have code that looks extremely similar to this.
        final FacebookHandler fbHandler = new FacebookHandler(new ILogin() {
            @Override //method called after calling fbHandler.login();
            public void loginAttemptResponse(boolean wasSuccessful) {
                //is login was successful, check the Switch, otherwise, uncheck it.
                facebookSwitch.setChecked(wasSuccessful);
                //re-enable the Switch since login/logout activity is finished.
                facebookSwitch.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        //This code block handles what happens when you press the Switch.
        facebookSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //disable the switch when attempting to login/logout
                facebookSwitch.setEnabled(false);

                //if the Switch isn't checked, log in.
                if(!facebookSwitch.isChecked())
                    fbHandler.login();
                else
                    fbHandler.logout(); //User already logged in, so log out.
            }
        });
    }
}
```